# Help me to see which function is called with firebug

Tags: jquery, firebug

how to see what jquery function is being called when i place a mouse on a left side bar. see the site [webspiders.com](http://webspiders.com) and place mouse on left side bar just top of the contact us side bar. please help

Comment: It's unclear what you are looking for. The hover on that works. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: The FireQuery plugin for firebug is useful for showing functions attached to DOM elements http://firequery.binaryage.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the code and search for that div's class, `.slide-out-div`. It's also dependent on **jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js**

```
$(function(){
        $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
            tabHandle: '.handle',
            pathToTabImage: 'images/tab.gif',
            imageHeight: '163px',
            imageWidth: '36px',
            tabLocation: 'left',
            speed: 300,
            action: 'hover',
            topPos: '140px',
            //leftPos: '20px',
            fixedPosition: true
        });

    });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i asked different question. i want that when i will point my mouse on slide-out-div then i was to see what jquery function is associated with this div. how to do it with firebug. please help.

Comment: also tell me what technique u used to know that what function is being invoked. u said  $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({}) this function is going to call. how do u know that tabSlideOut function is associated with the div. how do u find out with firebug. please explain.

Comment: Visual Event may help (http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event). My technique was simply looking through the source code. The slide-out div had a unique class (slide-out-div) and I searched through the javascript until I found the function attached to that class.

Comment: Also, using Firebug, click the "arrow" next to the firebug icon in the firebug menu bar. You can then move your mouse over any element on the page (highlighted blue) and the HTML for that element will be shown in the console.